# Need to figure out a pattern to make the same code work for both api and normal rendering

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, express

How do I make my node.js application to render JSON on api call and also render pages for normal call using design pattern?
Example:
mysite.com/products - is rendering product page.
I want to make mysite.com/api/products - to render JSON format of that page using existing routes.

Comment: this doesn't make any sense, your example has `mysite.com/products` and `mysite.com/api/products` which are clearly two different routes, but you ask how to make the second use an existing route.  Even if this made sense, you are breaking the SRP (Single Responsibility Principle), and you would only be confusing both your api consumers and your colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can suggest is to override render method of response object, and decide base on request condition:

```
var app = module.exports = (global.express = require('express'))();
var render = express.response.render;
express.response.render = function(view, options, callback) {
    this.locals.xhr = this.req.xhr; // Now you can use xhr var in layouts
    // if the accept header is json output json, change it with your request condition
    if (this.req.headers.accept === 'application/json') this.json(options);         
    else render.apply(this, arguments);
};
```